# Combining Access Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vba

I have a central database that is kept on a network that stores part numbers & descriptions for various components for machines. Often times individuals will need to use an offline copy during design and will add new entries to it. Is there a script to find the differences and update the master file that is on the network? I played around with union queries but I'm struggling to be able to update the original file and original table. My sql/microsoft access knowledge is limited.

For sake of clarity let's call the files as such:

Network Database: Network_DB.mdb

Offline Database: Offline_DB.mdb

Table: MISC_CAT

Comment: So is in MySQL or MS Access? Don't see any VBA here either.

Comment: Pretty sure this is purely an MS Access question.

Comment: I would say it might both MS Access and/or VBA. If there are some MS Access tools to get this done then please share. If I need to try to write a VBA script to accomplish this then let's go that route. Unfortunately I'm in the fog of even where to start.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience a generic solution is pretty difficult.  I tend to store the field names I want in a table then run the relevant update:

```
Public Function UpdateData()
Dim db As Database
Dim qd As QueryDef
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

On Error GoTo Err_UpdateData

    Set db = CodeDb

    strSQL = "SELECT fldName FROM MyTables WHERE tblName = 'MISC_CAT'"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

    Do Until rs.EOF
        strSQL = "UPDATE MISC_CAT_Network INNER JOIN MISC_CAT_Offline ON MISC_CAT_Network.KeyID = MISC_CAT_Offline.KeyID " & _
            "SET MISC_CAT_Network.[" & rs!fldName & "] = [MISC_CAT_Offline].[" & rs!fldName & "] " & _
            "WHERE (((Nz([MISC_CAT_Network].[" & rs!fldName & "],''))<>Nz([MISC_CAT_Offline].[" & rs!fldName & "],'')))"
        db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
    rs.Close
    db.Close

Exit_UpdateData:
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set qd = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_UpdateData:
    Debug.Print "Error - " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_UpdateData

End Function
```